# Getting the text between 2 round Brackets in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the table schema between first and the last round brackets of the table definition. What should be the Python regex pattern for it.

```
create table "informix".bank_info
  (
    bank_num char(4) not null ,
    merchant_num char(16) not null ,
    batch_date date not null ,
    batch_id integer not null ,
    transaction_id integer not null ,
    control_id integer
  );

create unique index "informix".bank_info_pk on "informix"
    .be_bt_store_rr (bank_num) using btree ;
```

output should be:

```
    bank_num char(4) not null ,
    merchant_num char(16) not null ,
    batch_date date not null ,
    batch_id integer not null ,
    transaction_id integer not null ,
    control_id integer
```

I tried multiple regex  but it not working.

```
matches = re.findall(r'([^\(.*?\);$])', text_file.read())
matches = re.findall(r'(.*);$',text_file.read())
matches = re.findall(r'(.*?");"', text_file.read())
```

Code:

```
import re
with open('bank_info.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    #matches = re.findall(r'([^\(.*?\);$])', text_file.read())
    matches=re.findall(r'(.*);$',text_file.read())
    #matches = re.findall(r'(.*?");"', text_file.read())
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

Expected Output:

```
bank_num char(4) not null ,
merchant_num char(16) not null ,
batch_date date not null ,
batch_id integer not null ,
transaction_id integer not null ,
control_id integer
```

Comment: Tried reading the Python documentation for `re`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html - Use the flags parameter to apply `re.MULTILINE`

Comment: D’oh I meant re.DOTALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pattern = r"\(\s*\n(.*?)\n\s*\);"` which means:

- `\(` the opening bracket (we have to escape the character with a backslash)
- `\s*\n` possible whitespace after the opening bracket and finally a newline
- `(.*?)` the group of lines we'd like as the final result (`*?` means non-greedy `*` quantifier, otherwise the newline and whitespace of the next line would be matched too)
- `\n\s*` newline and possible whitespace in the line of the closing bracket
- `\);` the closing bracket (we have to escape the character with a backslash) and the semicolon

Also note, that we have to use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag to make `.` match newlines.

```py
import re

text = """create table "informix".bank_info
  (
    bank_num char(4) not null ,
    merchant_num char(16) not null ,
    batch_date date not null ,
    batch_id integer not null ,
    transaction_id integer not null ,
    control_id integer
  );

create unique index "informix".bank_info_pk on "informix"
    .be_bt_store_rr (bank_num) using btree ;"""

pattern = r"\(\s*\n(.*?)\n\s*\);"
match = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.DOTALL)[0]
print(match)
```

Which prints:

```
    bank_num char(4) not null ,
    merchant_num char(16) not null ,
    batch_date date not null ,
    batch_id integer not null ,
    transaction_id integer not null ,
    control_id integer
```

If you want to remove the indentation, you can use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent):

```py
import textwrap
match = textwrap.dedent(match)
print(match)
```

Which prints:

```
bank_num char(4) not null ,
merchant_num char(16) not null ,
batch_date date not null ,
batch_id integer not null ,
transaction_id integer not null ,
control_id integer
```